# Aggregate root and existing data (from db)

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to play by-the-book and have a hard time grasping if there is some single line of thinking about this...

Lets say I have usual `ShoppingCart`. As user browse the shop he can add `ShoppingCartOrderLines` to cart. Each step is saved to DB. Lets imagine, for whatever reason, that there is maximum amount that a user can spent per shopping session meaning that sum of all `ShoppingCartOrderLines` cannot exceed certain amount.

So, `ShoppingCart` would be my AggregateRoot. Now, when adding new `ShoppingCardOrderLines` i would first need to pull existing ones from DB, create Aggregate root and then invoke `AR.AddItemToCart(Item)` on that instance.

How should this flow done from DDD perspective?
Should i have repository pulling all `ShoppingCartOrderLines` for given Cart and add them to the AT instance looping the same `AR.AddItemToCart(Item)` method (this being done in some domain service)? Or should my repository return AR filled with all data from DB directly? Or some third way? Maybe have dedicated constructor with one of the parameters being collection of `Items` already saved in Db?

I'd like to find some consistent way for this because if i end up reading whole aggregate roots on read side that might get extremely big/complex very quickly. Also, from what i've read on several places, enforcing rules (the ones in `AR.AddItemToCart(Item)`) should be done on write side only which would imply that when reading it from DB it should be done some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDD is relatively non prescriptive about that. It is dictated more by your context, constraints and own preference.

> Should i have repository pulling all ShoppingCartOrderLines for given
>   Cart and add them to the AT instance looping the same
>   AR.AddItemToCart(Item) method (this being done in some domain
>   service)? Or should my repository return AR filled with all data from
>   DB directly?

- The former is what you would do in an Event Sourcing scenario. You
  replay all events against the same aggregate transition functions
  that the front facing application would use and end up with an
  up-to-date loaded Aggregate.
- The latter is what happens with a more traditional state-based
  persistence like an RDBMS. Here, Aggregate rehydration usually goes
  through a totally different path than your front-facing domain operations
  because you load everything in one go, basically bypassing the domain. You don't have successive small transformations where invariants must be checked. 
  The Repository should be able to autonomously query the database and turn the data into a full fledged Aggregate. There are different techniques to achieve this while preserving Entity encapsulation - giving the persistence layer access to a protection level that allows it to modify fields that would normally be only available to the Domain, creating an intermediate data object that the Entity can "absorb", etc.

Comment: Thank you for this response...you've nailed my dilemma! First approach seems to be more robust for many different scenarios but also i feel it might be a huge overkill for most of the situations. But main info is that there is no single, correct solution with regards to that.

Answer (score 1):

> How should this flow done from DDD perspective?

The usual pattern follows the description in the [Blue Book](http://a.co/3Td2pWQ): the repository provides an instance of the Root.

Part of the point here being that neither the application, nor the domain model, have any interest or investment in the details of how the aggregate is stored -- the repository insulates the other components from the knowledge of whether the persisted representation of the data is rows in an RDBMS, a document in a document store, or simply bytes on disk.

This often means that the repository needs something like a builder/factory (implemented by the domain model), so that it can convert the persisted representation into the (current) domain model's in memory representation.

> If we assume domain model doesn't have setters does that mean repository actually goes through usual domains interface (methods) to set instance which actually means enforcing all rules again on read side?

There's an important thing to recognize here: the *read side* shouldn't be enforcing any rules at all.  That's the write model's job.

But: if you need to be converting domain agnostic bytes to domain model values, or converting unvalidated value objects to validated value objects; the logic for those conversions is provided by the domain model.

Comment: If we assume domain model doesnt have setters does that mean repository actually goes through usual domains interface (methods) to set instance which actually means enforcing all rules again on read side? Or should domain expose build/factory (static) methods that repository should use?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what confuses me. I understand that enforcing rules is write model's job. But in the example of `ShoppingCart` i provided, assuming we didnt just blindly expose items collection that anyone can set to anything, effectively that means that whenever repository builds an instance of write model to add new item on top of already added ones, it would have no other way other than enforcing rules again on all items. Correct?